# How to get rid of CSS Table element in each cell of a column in my excel extract

Tags: css, excel, conditional-statements

I need to delete the CSS table element  in each cell of Column X that came along with my JIRA extract in a particular column. The data in each cell of Column X looks like:

```
.table-grid-simple-mode{
        overflow-y:auto;
         display:block;
}
.table-grid-simple-mode, .table-grid-simple-mode th, .table-grid-simple-mode td{
        border: 1px solid #c1c7d0;
         padding: 3px;
}
.table-grid-simple-mode table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-grid-simple-mode tr:hover{
        background-color: # ffffffff;
}
.table-grid-simple-mode tr{
        height: 33px;
}
.table-grid-simple-mode metaheader {
        background-color:#ffffff;
}

Text I want to keep
```

Comment: It is not clear *exactly* what you are asking since you can just delete the extra text. Please provide additional information on what the situation is (For example: "When I open my JIRA exported file in Excel..." and what result you want

Comment: @ChrisSc Updated, is this better? Essentially, every cell under column X has this CSS table element I need gone

Comment: I'm going to assume you are loading the contents into Excel (or another spreadsheet app). You can use the `replace` feature of the app to remove the text you don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User ChrisSc answered above as a comment. Thanks @ChrisSc

Comment: You can edit your post and quote the commented answer, or tell @ChrisSc to post an answer so that it can be accepted as such. "Thank you posts" without specific information are not considered as adding value to StackOverflow though, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/where-should-i-say-thank-you-on-stack-overflow